# Blank ViewController after calloutAccessoryControlTapped

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a `MKMapView` and some markers on the map. When user taps a marker an `MKAnnotationView` comes up with a `title` and a `button` of type `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`.

When the user taps the button it should go to another `viewController`. The problem is that when the new `viewController` comes up , it is blank and it doesn't have the format that I have gave it in the storyboard.

Here is the code for `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    MnhmeioViewController * destViewController = [[MnhmeioViewController alloc] init];

    Annotation *which=view.annotation;
    NSString *whichString=which.title;

    Group *tmpGroup;

    for(int i=0; i<allGroups.count; i++) {

        Group *checkGroup=[allGroups objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([checkGroup.title isEqualToString:whichString]) {
            tmpGroup=checkGroup;
            break;
        }
    }

    NSString *mnhmeioName=tmpGroup.title;
    destViewController.titleNavBar = mnhmeioName;
    destViewController.selectedArthro = tmpGroup;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the MnhmeioViewController with NibName or identifier from Storyboard. Also make your MnhmeioViewController as property on class level , it is better approach when adding view controllers.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
MnhmeioViewController * destViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MnhmeioViewController"];
```

Comment: I get the exception "No known class method for selector "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier".

Comment: Make sure that identifier you have given for your view controller in the storyboard, you are instantiating with the same identifier, and initilize your storyboard also

Comment: I had to initialize my storyboard. Many Thanks!

Comment: yes this is what i wrote in the above comment, good that you fixed it.